# Change div HTML content with attribute from button on click

Tags: javascript, html, custom-data-attribute

I have some data attributes on buttons that I need to send as content to a div when those buttons are clicked. A part of my code until now is this:

```js
function getDiscount() {

  var buttons = document.querySelectorAll(".form-button");

  buttons.forEach(function(item, index) {
    item.addEventListener('click', function() {
      var discount = getDiscount(this);
    });
  });

  function getDiscount(clicked_element) {
    var val = clicked_element.getAttribute("data-discount");
    return val;
  }
};
```

```html
<div class="discount__Topics">
<div><strong class="discount-amount">50</strong>%</div>

<div class="offers"> 
  <button class="form-button" data-discount="38">Offer 1</button>
  <button class="form-button" data-discount="50">Offer 2</button>
  <button class="form-button" data-discount="22">Offer 3</button>
  <button class="form-button" data-discount="88">Offer 4</button>
</div>
</div>

<div class="discount__Topics">
<div><strong class="discount-amount">60</strong>%</div>

<div class="offers"> 
  <button class="form-button" data-discount="12">Offer 1</button>
  <button class="form-button" data-discount="32">Offer 2</button>
  <button class="form-button" data-discount="44">Offer 3</button>
  <button class="form-button" data-discount="55">Offer 4</button>
</div>
</div>
```

I'm just not seeing how to change the html with attribute when it's clicked and how to have two sets of buttons or more on the same page.

Hope someone can help.
Many thanks

UPDATE: Now the code is running properly but im having troubles with getting multiples div's with multiple buttons working. I've created a for.Each wic logs my div correctly but im not beeing able to have the working properly.

```js
var discounters = document.querySelectorAll(".discount__Topics");

discounters.forEach((index) => {
    console.log(index)

    var buttons = document.querySelectorAll(".form-button");

    buttons.forEach(function (item) {
        item.addEventListener('click', function(){    
            var discount = getDiscount(this);
            let span = document.querySelector('.discount-amount')
            span.innerHTML = '<strong>' + discount+ '</strong>'
        });
    });

    function getDiscount(clicked_element) {
        var val = clicked_element.getAttribute("data-discount");  
        return val;
    }

});
```

```html
<div class="discount__Topics">
<div><strong class="discount-amount">38</strong>%</div>

<div class="offers"> 
  <button class="form-button" data-discount="38">Offer 1</button>
  <button class="form-button" data-discount="50">Offer 2</button>
  <button class="form-button" data-discount="22">Offer 3</button>
  <button class="form-button" data-discount="88">Offer 4</button>
</div>
</div>

<div class="discount__Topics">
<div><strong class="discount-amount">12</strong>%</div>

<div class="offers"> 
  <button class="form-button" data-discount="12">Offer 1</button>
  <button class="form-button" data-discount="32">Offer 2</button>
  <button class="form-button" data-discount="44">Offer 3</button>
  <button class="form-button" data-discount="55">Offer 4</button>
</div>
</div>
```

Comment: FYI, your markup has a flaw. You're closing a `span` element with a `strong` tag.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You have defined two functions called `getDiscount`, it would be better to let them have different name

### ```js
function init(){

    var buttons = document.querySelectorAll(".form-button");

        buttons.forEach(function (item, index) {
            item.addEventListener('click', function(){    
                var discount = getDiscount(this);
                let span = document.querySelector('.discount-amount')
                span.innerHTML = '<strong>' + discount+ '</strong>%'
                //span.innerHTML =discount.bold()+ '%' // we can use bold() instead
            });
        });

        function getDiscount(clicked_element) {
            var val = clicked_element.getAttribute("data-discount");  
            return val;
        }
};

init()
```

```html
<div><span class="discount-amount"><strong>55</strong>%</div>

<div class="offers"> 

<button class="form-button" data-discount="38">Offer 1</button>
<button class="form-button" data-discount="50">Offer 2</button>
<button class="form-button" data-discount="22">Offer 3</button>
<button class="form-button" data-discount="88">Offer 4</button>
</div>
```

Update:
for your updated question,since it has multiple button groups and divs,so we need to sepereate them correctly.

One solution is to using index,change

```
let span = document.querySelector('.discount-amount')
```

to

```
let span = document.querySelectorAll('.discount-amount')[Math.floor(index/4)]
```

In my opinios,the best way is to let them have different id or class,so that we can query them easily.

```js
function init(){

    var buttons = document.querySelectorAll(".form-button");

        buttons.forEach(function (item, index) {
            item.addEventListener('click', function(){    
                var discount = getDiscount(this);
                let span = document.querySelectorAll('.discount-amount')[Math.floor(index/4)]
                span.innerHTML = '<strong>' + discount+ '</strong>%'
                //span.innerHTML =discount.bold()+ '%' // we can use bold() instead
            });
        });

        function getDiscount(clicked_element) {
            var val = clicked_element.getAttribute("data-discount");  
            return val;
        }
};

init()
```

```html
<div class="discount__Topics">
<div><strong class="discount-amount">50</strong>%</div>

<div class="offers"> 
  <button class="form-button" data-discount="38">Offer 1</button>
  <button class="form-button" data-discount="50">Offer 2</button>
  <button class="form-button" data-discount="22">Offer 3</button>
  <button class="form-button" data-discount="88">Offer 4</button>
</div>
</div>

<div class="discount__Topics">
<div><strong class="discount-amount">60</strong>%</div>

<div class="offers"> 
  <button class="form-button" data-discount="12">Offer 1</button>
  <button class="form-button" data-discount="32">Offer 2</button>
  <button class="form-button" data-discount="44">Offer 3</button>
  <button class="form-button" data-discount="55">Offer 4</button>
</div>
</div>
```

Comment: Thanks it works great! I just have one more issue, what if i have more than one set of buttons on same page? I wrap my code in a new div and duplicated it. I've tried doing a forEach based on the class but no luck

Comment: @kyllaz I am going to sleep,can you post a new question? Or update your question,will see it tomorrow

Comment: Yes of course! See you tomorrow =)

Comment: @kyllaz,have updated my answer,you can check it now

Comment: Thanks @lucumt. The solution works great here but it's a bit limited for what i need. When i add it to my full code i get and error on the span.innerhtml, and this way if i have more buttons or div's it also stops working, isnt the any other way of working with ilimited number of divs and buttons? I've tried doing it with an array but it doesnt work properly, i can print the divs on console but it always change the first div elements. I'm going to update my code maybe it can be fixed. Thanks again for your help

Comment: @kyllaz I would suggest you to post a new question about it

Answer (score 0):

If I understand your question correctly, you are looking for something like this.

```js
var buttons = document.querySelectorAll(".form-button");
var discountRef = document.querySelector(".discount-amount");

function setDiscount(pointerEvent) {
    // get the clicked button from the pointerEvent
    var discount = pointerEvent.target.dataset.discount

    // add the discount to <span class="discount-amount"></span>
    discountRef.innerText = discount
}

buttons.forEach(function (item) {
    item.addEventListener('click', setDiscount);
});
```